Why does entropy obey the superposition principle?
I was deriving the Boltzmann's entropy formula
$${\displaystyle S=k_{\mathrm {B} }\ln \Omega}$$
We start with two prepositions:

Let's consider two systems and we know the entropy of the first is $S_1$ and of the second $S_2$. If we want to know the entropy of both systems, it should be

$$S_{12}=S_1+S_2\tag1$$

The probability of a state of the first system is $p_1$ and of the second $p_2$. So the probability of the global state of those two systems is:

$$p_{12}=p_1\cdot p_2$$
If $S=f(p)$ than we should have a function:
$$f(p_1)+f(p_2) = f(p_1\cdot p_2)$$
from which by differentiating and integrating we obtain the Boltzmann's entropy formula.
How do we know that equation $(1)$ is true? Why does entropy obey the superposition principle? Is that something from classical thermodynamics or can it be shown only outside of it?

Entropy, in classical equilibrium thermodynamics, is assumed to be extensive.

I think you are confusing the causes and consequences here. First of all, Boltzmann did not introduce the concept of Entropy $S$, Clausius did and it was an extensive additive property by definition (because it was defined through heat, itself an additive quantity). Instead, Boltzmann had a brilliant idea that entropy has something to do with numbers of possible microstates (or, equivalently, the probabilities of macrostates). Then, knowing that probabilities $p$ are combined multiplicatively, he realized that if $S=f(p)$, then $f(x)$ must be a logarithmic function. You see there is no "derivation" here, the key thing was the realization that entropy is related to (macro-)state probabilities. The rest comes as if by itself.

How do we know that heat is an additive quantity?

From experience. Say, if you need 1J to heat 1 g of certain material by 1 degree K, the experience says you'll need 2J for a 2g sample.
